# Finding the latest and uniq entry in a many-to-many table in rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been trying out Rails for a month now. I really enjoying it!
But I got a problem, hopefully someone out there can help me!

My database is simple with 3 tables:
User(id, Name)
User_status_code(id, status_code_id, user_id, timestamps)
status_code(id,description) (status are: 1= Created, 2= Active, 3= Inactive, 4=deleted)

The User table has a many-to-many relationship to status_code through user_status_code.

How can I find all the users which has the status_id=3(inactive) but not status_id=4(deleted)? 
and
How can I get a distinct list of users with the latest status_id based on 'created_at' in the user_status_code table?

Example:
In user_status_code I have 7 entries with 3 users:
Id, user_id, status_code_id, created_at
1, 1, 1, 15-12-2010
2, 1, 2, 16-12-2010
3, 2, 1, 15-12-2010
4, 3, 1, 17-12-2010
5, 3, 2, 20-12-2010
6, 3, 3, 21-12-2010
7, 3, 4, 22-12-2010

How can i display the latest status for all the users?
Here is what i want:
2, 1, 2, 16-12-2010
3, 2, 1, 15-12-2010
7, 3, 4, 22-12-2010

(Sorry for my English)
/Christian

Comment: OT: I don't know any details about your application, but I'm wondering about those stati — "Created, Active, Inactive and Deleted" sound very exclusive to me. Does a user have more than one status at a time and is that really necessary? If not, you could e.g. use something like statemachine to solve "all your problems",… well some of them ;).

Comment: thanks for answering.I need to keep track of all the previous states of the user.

Comment: Maybe I can include the status entity in the user table and create a logtable, which holds track of all the previous states of a user.

Comment: Hi, I'm attempting to figure out answers to your questions. It's hard to demonstrate an answer to your first question because in your example table there are no users that are inactive but not deleted (user 3 is both, users 1 & 2 are neither).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question 1

I'm sure there's a prettier way to do it with some kind of left outer join but this seems to work with a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM user_status_codes
WHERE status_code_id = 3 AND user_id NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT user_id
   FROM user_status_codes
   WHERE status_code_id = 4)
```

#### Question 2

This is an example of a [groupwise aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Again, there's probably a cleaner and faster method but try this:

```
SELECT user_id, status_code_id, created_at
FROM user_status_codes t1
WHERE created_at =
  (SELECT MAX(created_at)
   FROM user_status_codes t2
   WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

It should be a trivial matter to map both of these queries to their respective AR objects.